# Number of minimal elements of product order

Tags: posets

Consider three sets: $A = \{1,2,\dotsc,n_A\}$, $B=\{1,2,\dotsc,n_B\}$, and $C=\{1,2,\dotsc,n_C\}$, where $n_A, n_B, n_C \ge 2$. Define a product order (which is a partial order) on the cartesian product $A \times B \times C$. In other words, $(a,b,c) \le (a',b',c')$ if and only if $a \le a'$, $b \le b'$, and $c \le c'$.

Let $T$ be a non-empty subset of $A \times B \times C$. We call the triple $(a,b,c) \in T$ *minimal* if there is no triple $(a',b',c') \in T$, $(a,b,c) \neq (a',b',c')$, such that $(a',b',c') \le (a,b,c)$.

My question is what is the maximum possible number of minimal triples in $T$?

**Some particular (simplest) cases**

If $(1,1,1) \in T$, then obviously the only minimal triple in $T$ is $(1,1,1)$ (all the other triples will be larger).

If $T = A \times B \times C \setminus \{(1,1,1)\}$, then there are three minimal triples: $(2,1,1)$, $(1,2,1)$, and $(1,1,2)$.

But what are potential answers in general case? And what is the answer when we have more than three sets?

Comment: You're looking for the width (i.e., size of the largest antichain) of the product of chains (btw, you mix up minimal and maximal a lot in the post). See this question on Math Stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299770/width-of-a-product-of-chains.

Comment: Fixed minimal/maximal (it was late night when I was typing :) )

Comment: And thanks for the link!

Comment: Try looking at Theorem 4.1.1 in Anderson, "Combinatorics of Finite Sets."